# DirectX sampling a Texture2DArray interpolates between textures unintentionally

Tags: directx

I'm trying to texture my procedurally generated terrain. Previously I used an array of textures e.g. `Texture tex[8]`, however in the shader you can't access this by index unless you chain if statements (ew), so I switched to using a `Texture2DArray` where instead you use a 3D UV where the Z component is the texture index. I use texassemble to generate a DDS file containing the Texture2DArray so it can be loaded in with ease.

For whatever reason, DirectX(11) seems to interpolate the Z component whenever the Z changes, resulting in seeing a slice of other textures in the array. I should add I'm trying to change the texture on the same piece of geometry. But I need to do this due to having multiple procedurally generated biomes.

---

I sample the texture in the pixel shader like so

```
float4 texCol = Tex.Sample(Sampler, v.UV);
```

---

My sampler is set up like this

```
CD3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc(D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC,
    D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP,
    0.f, maxAnisotropy, D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER, border, 0.f, FLT_MAX);
```

---

The unwanted interpolation in question

[image: Texture boundary interpolates?]

Comment: DirectX interpolates your Z because you have triangles which have different Z's on different corners. Fix your UVs.

Comment: I will add to the above comment, at the seams where there are different texture indices (z value in this case), you will need to have seperate vertices for each different texture at the seam to ensure you do not get interpolation.